# _SplashScreenViewState#32282(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/splash_screen_view) package for my Splash Screen. And after upgrading to the Flutter 2.2.3 version, I'm getting the below errors. Whenever I reinstall the app it always shows this warning in logs. It says `dispose()` the `AnimationController` but I haven't created any `AnimationController`.  Thanks for the help :)

Below is my Code

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppStatusBar.setColor();
    return SplashScreenView(
      imageSrc: ImageConstants.kLogoImage,
      navigateRoute: LoginScreen(),
      duration: 1500,
      imageSize: 100,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the console messages

```dart
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
_SplashScreenViewState#32282(ticker active) was disposed with an active Ticker.

_SplashScreenViewState created a Ticker via its SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. The Ticker must be disposed before calling super.dispose().

Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.

The offending ticker was: Ticker(created by _SplashScreenViewState#32282(lifecycle state: created))
The stack trace when the Ticker was actually created was:
#0      new Ticker.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/scheduler/ticker.dart:67
#1      new Ticker
package:flutter/…/scheduler/ticker.dart:69
#2      SingleTickerProviderStateMixin.createTicker
package:flutter/…/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:129
#3      new AnimationController
package:flutter/…/animation/animation_controller.dart:247
#4      _SplashScreenViewState.initState
package:splash_screen_view/SplashScreenView.dart:126
#5      StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4711
#6      ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4548
...     Normal element mounting (172 frames)
#178    Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3611
#179    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6221
#180    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6232
...     Normal element mounting (345 frames)
#525    Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3611
#526    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3363
#527    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1189
#528    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1159
#529    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1104
#530    BuildOwner.buildScope
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2535
#531    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1103
#532    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:937
#533    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:917
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      SingleTickerProviderStateMixin.dispose.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:142
#1      SingleTickerProviderStateMixin.dispose
package:flutter/…/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:156
#2      _SplashScreenViewState.dispose
package:splash_screen_view/SplashScreenView.dart:149
#3      StatefulElement.unmount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4800
#4      _InactiveElements._unmount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1847
```

Comment: Please add your code as well.